# Is the Falcon 9 launch/landing telemetry data available for visualisation purposes?

Tags: spacex, falcon-9, raw-data

If like to visualize the launch and landing, maybe tied into the audio.

Comment: Beyond what's visible in the launch broadcast? Very unlikely. They're a commercial company that likes to keep things private. Even basic stuff like dimensions of the stages are not published.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not public. This level of detailed information in the United States would fall under ITAR, and as a point of fact, SpaceX is more secretive with this kind of data than other launch providers, you have to pretty much be a SpaceX employee, or contractor, or government agency, to see any of the information.

Specifically, [ITAR Item 12 Category II includes](http://fas.org/spp/starwars/offdocs/itar/p121.htm)

> (3) Software which processes post-flight, recorded data, enabling determination of vehicle position throughout its flight path (see § 121.1, Category IV(i)).

Answer (score 3):

Try [SpaceXtract on github](https://github.com/shahar603/SpaceXtract). It captures telemetry data directly from the spacex's webcast video feed. From the same author (shahar603), there is also a Telemetry-Data repository containing a collection of telemetry data from spacex past flights.

Comment: Cool answer! I've just asked [Do SpaceX and other US-based launch companies get “ITAR waivers” for live-broadcasting processed telemetry data?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/44998/12102)