# Do SpaceX and other US-based launch companies get "ITAR waivers" for live-broadcasting processed telemetry data?

Tags: law, tracking, united-states, regulatory, telemetry

The [17-Feb-2016 answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/14129/12102) to *Is the Falcon 9 launch/landing telemetry data available for visualisation purposes?* explains that access to telemetry data is controlled by ITAR and/or other regulations, but [today's answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/44993/12102) points out that the SpaceX webcast video feed do contain processed versions of telemetry and tracking data and links to [SpaceXtract on github](https://github.com/shahar603/SpaceXtract) as a way to extract that data.

These two "No" and "Yes" answers are not necessarily in conflict because the interpretations of what is or is not "telemetry data" are different.

Do SpaceX and other US-based launch companies get "ITAR waivers" for live-broadcasting processed telemetry data, or is this kind of information explicitly excluded from the regulations?

For comparison, ISRO and JAXA live video broadcasts sometimes show even more detailed telemetry data, but of course [ITAR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Traffic_in_Arms_Regulations) applies (in this case) to US launches.

---

GIF from [What is the extra moving and disappearing line in the animation in the BulgariaSat-1 webcast?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/22084/12102) illustrating some of the processed telemetry and tracking data shown

[image: GIF from screen shots of SpaceX video of BulgariaSat-1 webcast]

Comment: different but related; wasn't there some "thing" about a camera on a SpaceX launch that had to be turned off, or a live broadcast was blocked or something?

Comment: yes, the rear view camera had to be licensed

Comment: @JCRM ah, thanks! Searching "SpaceX regulations camera" I found this; is this it? [Why does the NOAA require a permit to be issued to stream images of the earth?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/26332/12102) If so, then it doesn't directly apply to this question about telemetry data.